# It came out with the wrong sort

Tags: python

it doesn't give the medal standings correctly, I didn't understand where I made a mistake in the code. In fact, the athlete with the least time should get a gold medal, while bronze gets a medal.

```
dict_time = {}
# loop through the athlete dictionary
for item in athelete:
    # store the key of the dict_time as name and country and value as time in seconds
    dict_time[item,athelete[item][0]] = athelete[item][1][0]*3600 + athelete[item][1][1]*60 + athelete[item][1][2]
count = 0
medals = ['Gold Medal','Silver Medal','Bronze Medal']
countryDict = {}
print()
# print the medalists
for item in sorted(dict_time):
    if count == 3:
        break
    else:
        print(medals[count]+": "+item[0][0]+" "+item[0][1]+", "+item[1])
    count += 1
    countryDict[item[1]] = [item[0], dict_time[item]]
```

INPUT

Spyridon Louis -- GRE-- 2,58,50

Kharilaos Vasilakos --GRE-- 3,06,03

Gyula Kellner -- HUN-- 3,06,35

OUTPUT

Gold Medal: Gyula Kellner, HUN

Silver Medal: Kharilaos Vasilakos, GRE

Bronze Medal: Spyridon Louis, GRE

Comment: What's your question? If you're looking for debugging help, you need to make a [mre] including complete but minimal code (like to start, `athelete` is not defined) and expected output. You can [edit] to clarify. For more tips, see [ask].

Comment: this is an assignment that others shouldn't copy, so I threw out some of it.

Answer (score 0):

You're looping over a sorted list of keys by the key values and not by dictionary values. Moreover, You're sorting in increasing order and you should sort in descending order.

Therefore, I would use:

```
sorted(dict_time.keys(), key=dict_time.get, reverse=True)
```